# Trouble with doc comments

Tags: java, javadoc

```
/** Checks to make sure that the @param ch is not a white space, if so returns true, if not returns false*/
public static boolean isWhiteSpace(char ch)
{
    if(ch == ' ')
        return true; 
    else
        return false;
}
```

I was writing doc comments, and when I used the `@param` feature, it followed into my doc comments. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Can you provide some code with the accordant Javadoc?

Comment: Off topic, but the method you've written is neither correct nor even necessary. White space includes more than just the space character. See [Character.isWhitespace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supposed to happen.  `@param` is not what is considered a [block tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags), so it cannot be placed in that section.

The *only* place you can place `@param` is in the tag section.

To that end, *avoid* writing Javadoc like this.  You want to describe the behavior as opposed to relying on the variable in this context anyway.

Something like this would be better:

```
/** Checks to see if the provided argument is a space.
 * @param ch the character passed through
 * @return true if the character is a space, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isWhiteSpaceChar(char ch) {
    // impl
}
```

[Take a gander at the official style guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide) for more context into this.

Comment: Thanks, that helps more. I was just told to add them and I assumed that the formatting would be different in the Javadoc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

To make a JavaDoc comment, you start by doing this:

```
/**
 *  Checks to see if a character contains a whitespace character or not.
 *
 *  @param ch Character to check for whitespace
 */
```

EDIT: You usually don't refer to a variable in the description, but below it.

Comment: I was told that I "must use doc comments, and include the method tags param and return (if they apply)  for all methods I define."

Comment: Alright, so under the `@param` you'd do `@return True if the character contains whitespace, false otherwise.`